# Elastic search doesn't find document with "-" in it

Tags: php, api, elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

I have a query in ES:

```
POST <index>/_search
{
  
   "_source":[
      <list_of_fields_to_return>
   ],
   "size":"6",
   "from":"0",
   "min_score": 10,
   "query":{
      "function_score":{
         "functions":[
            {
               "field_value_factor":{
                  "field":"product.sales_count",
                  "missing":0,
                  "modifier":"log1p"
               }
            },
            {
               "field_value_factor":{
                  "field":"product.image_count",
                  "missing":0,
                  "modifier":"log1p"
               }
            },
            {
               "field_value_factor":{
                  "field":"featureCount",
                  "missing":0,
                  "modifier":"log1p"
               }
            },
            {
               "field_value_factor":{
                  "field":"<field>",
                  "missing":0,
                  "modifier":"none",
                  "factor":5
               }
            },
            {
               "field_value_factor":{
                  "field":"<field>",
                  "missing":0,
                  "modifier":"none",
                  "factor":3
               }
            },
            {
               "field_value_factor":{
                  "field":"<field>",
                  "missing":0,
                  "modifier":"none",
                  "factor":2
               }
            },
            {
               "field_value_factor":{
                  "field":"<field>",
                  "missing":0,
                  "modifier":"none",
                  "factor":2
               }
            },
            {
               "field_value_factor":{
                  "field":"<field>",
                  "missing":0,
                  "modifier":"none",
                  "factor":1
               }
            }
         ],
         "score_mode":"sum",
         "query":{
            "bool":{
               "filter":[
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "product.is_visible":true
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "should":[
                  {
                     "query_string":{
                        "fields":[
                           <field>
                        ],
                        "query":"ALV3002688-SET~1"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "query_string":{
                        "fields":[
                           "<field>"
                        ],
                        "query":"ALV3002688-SET",
                        "boost":"2.0"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "query_string":{
                        "fields":[
                           "product.ref"
                        ],
                        "query":"*ALV3002688-SET*",    <---- PROBLEM WITH "-" sign
                        "boost": 10
                      
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "by_categories":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"<field>"
         }
      }
 }

}
```

If i strip the "-SET", it matches perfectly, can't wildcard search for "-"? For now, it just returns 0 matching documents. I could do something like, strip "-" and replace it with whitespace but then It gives me all documents for example "something\SET".

Also, If I remove the "*" sign it maches perfectly.

What am I missing?

Comment: it means that `product.ref` is probably a `text` field with a standard analyzer, and thus, `ALV3002688-SET` have been indexed into two different tokens `alv3002688` and `set`. Can you confirm by looking at your mapping?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, although I found something else. By looking at my analyzers, there is a custom filter applied ```filter_hyphen``` which is then applied to every analyzer.

Comment: There you go, glad you figured it out

Comment: Im glad too but can I disable that filter from my analyzer? What would be a good solution? Should I create a different analyzer without the hyper_filter and apply it to my product.ref?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing your mappings/settings and knowing more about your search use cases

Comment: most of the mappings are TEXT, analyzers are standard with some custom modifications like ```hypen_filter``` and ```html_strip```. I want to match the product.ref field even if it has weird characters

Comment: Also, aren't wildcard queries not analyzed by default ?

Comment: wildcard queries yes, but you have a query_string query with a wildcard... and the problem is not the search time analyzer but the index time analyzer, i.e. your content are already tokenized and analyzed into multiple tokens